# Basement floor crack

Tags: repair, concrete, basement, foundation, crack

I've lived in this house since April 2021. It was built in 1970. I don't know if it's just the lighting, but I never noticed this bump in the floor under the carpet before now. It looks like a crack. Is this concerning? I'm worried that it's hard to really get a look at under the carpet.  There is no moisture coming from the crack.
[image]

Comment: Might be able to pull up the carpet just a little at the "edges" to look down inside to see how it looks...

Comment: Rogerdpack has the correct idea, those marks are two straight for cracks in the cement. They may be where the carpet was seamed.